# Is using forms to submit data insecure

Tags: html, forms, security

I noticed while debugging with chrome built in debug tool the forms that submit data for facebook,twitter,tsu ...

But i noticed that they never use form tag to submit data

```
<form method="post" action="file.php">
   <input name="input_one" type="text">
   <input name="input_two" type="text">
</form>
```

But just use simple input and submit it with javascript .

```
<input name="input_two" type="text">
```

So i was wondering :

- Is using the plain traditional is more secure or via JavaScript and why ?

Comment: No, it is not any more or less secure. If you want security, use HTTPS for the data you submit/transport – whichever way that actually happens.

Comment: But why the vote down :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Traditional way of submitting the form:

Is just submitting the form on clicking the "submit" button, meaning that the form data will be posted to the same file ( The file is getting loaded with form data). You can write some PHP script to handle the form inputs.

### Javascript way of submitting the form:

The new way of submitting the form via javascript is using "AJAX" which submits the form and gets you the response without re-loading the page.

For security, use HTTPS than HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

No, submitting via form is not more insecure than submitting via JavaScript, which actually uses [`AJAX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started). Both methods support `GET` and `POST` and the browsers handles them the same way. As CBroe says the only way to send data secure is through `HTTPS`.